# Query Only the Highest Value of the Votes

Tags: c#

```
//query the list of winners of the said event
    public ActionResult List_of_Winners(int id=0) {
        var winners = (from cat in db.Events_Category_tbl
            join can in db.Candidates_Info_tbl on cat.events_category_id equals can.events_category_id
            where cat.events_info_id == id
            select new Candidates
            {
                events_category_name = cat.events_category_name,
                candidates_fullname = can.candidates_fullname,
                candidates_info_id = can.candidates_info_id,
                events_category_id = cat.events_category_id,
                no_of_votes = can.no_of_votes.Value
            }).Take(1).OrderBy(x=>can.no_of_votes);

        return PartialView(winners);
    }
```

In this code, Iam planning to get the highest no_of_votes in each category. But, I got an error with this one. How will I query into the database to get the data that I want?

This is the error displayed: "The name 'can' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Can you post the stack trace please?

Comment: Did not check the entire query, but at least you need to change `OrderBy(x=>can.no_of_votes)` to `OrderBy(x => x.no_of_votes)`.

Comment: Maybe `.OrderBy(x=>can.no_of_votes).Take(1)`?

Comment: Ive changed this already into `OrderBy(x=>x.no_of_votes)` but then I only get one category with the winner. How will I query all the category with the winner?

Comment: Well the `Take(1)` statement limits the number of returned results to 1. So I assume that is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, I will remove that one. I am planning to Select Distinct Top 1 from the candidates then how will I implement that one in linq query?

Comment: Guys, I need an answer..please help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to move where you have the orderby/take, I believe something like this should work:

```
var winners = from cat in db.Events_Category_tbl
              from can in
                  (from c in db.Candidates_Info_tbl
                   where c.events_category_id == cat.events_category_id
                   select c).OrderByDescending(c => c.no_of_votes).Take(1)
              where cat.events_info_id == id
              select new Candidates
              {
                  events_category_name = cat.events_category_name,
                  candidates_fullname = can.candidates_fullname,
                  candidates_info_id = can.candidates_info_id,
                  events_category_id = cat.events_category_id,
                  no_of_votes = can.no_of_votes.Value
              };
```

---

For ties something like this may work (should return everyone who got the highest score per category):

```
var winners = from cat in db.Events_Category_tbl
              from max_votes in
                  (from c in db.Candidates_Info_tbl
                   where c.events_category_id == cat.events_category_id
                   select c.no_of_votes).OrderByDescending(c => c).Take(1)
              join can in db.Candidates_Info_tbl on cat.events_category_id equals can.events_category_id
              where cat.events_info_id == id && can.no_of_votes == max_votes
              select new Candidates
              {
                  events_category_name = cat.events_category_name,
                  candidates_fullname = can.candidates_fullname,
                  candidates_info_id = can.candidates_info_id,
                  events_category_id = cat.events_category_id,
                  no_of_votes = can.no_of_votes.Value
              };
```

It could also be done with GroupBy's or different style inner queries, I imagine, but that 'from x in (from y in z where y.something = x.something select something).Take(n)' pattern results in [cross/outer apply](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) in SQL server which seems to perform well in most cases I've seen.

Comment: The candidate will display is not the one that has the highest votes.

Comment: Then, what if there is a tie? I mean, more than 1 candidates has the highest votes? What will I do?

Comment: Hmm, and bring back everyone who has the max no_of_votes for each category?

Comment: Yes. That would be better

Comment: Because in this query only the first candidate that has the highest votes will display but for some cases that there are more than one candidates got  the same highest votes or tie  it should be displayed too.

Comment: When I try to run your codes(tie), I've got an error

Comment: `System.Nullable<int>` does not contain definition for no_of_votes and no extension method 'no_of_votes' accepting a first argument of type `System.Nullable<int>`..

Comment: Oops, yeah, I updated the select in the sub query and not the order by, fixed.